# JMeter: Keycloak "User session not found " error with /protocol/openid-connect/token end point

Tags: jmeter, keycloak, openid-connect

I was trying to simulate **/protocol/openid-connect/token** Keycloak end point using JMeter. Even though  I have correlated code parameter and passing that properly. There is something called code_verifier and it is not found any of the previous requests. Providing the sample request and response for your reference. Can someone help me here if I have to take any additional steps to overcome this issue in the response attached.

Request:

```
POST https://{HOST}/auth/realms/{Appname}/protocol/openid-connect/token

POST data:
code=f99e9da5-cfcf-4069-aaec-b53mee00af54.e46a981h-5291-4862-b6fd-abc7f2d222f2.87488f77-3b05-47b0-afd7-8a8c80b384e7%0AContent-Length%3A+0%0ADate%3A+Wed%2C+29+Dec+2021+18%3A30%3A26+GMT%0A&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebclient-performance.appname.ad%2F&client_id=premium-web-client&code_verifier=YTlYTmoxZ2tXbzM1M0xkVkRfZXg0M280TUhDZXVMYVdIY2hoVzRqTE5ESXkw

Cookie Data:
AUTH_SESSION_ID=e46a61f9-5291-4862-b6fd-eff7f2d222f2.d306f6737649; KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=en; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJiZDBmYTc0Ni02Y2NmLTRiMjktYTBmZC1kOWMxMWNmY2RlM2UifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NDA4ODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY0MDgwMjYyNiwianRpIjoiZWFjZDczNDctNDYyNC00Mjk0LWE4NjYtYzRiYmM1MjNiMDlhIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly8xNzIuMjYuMjMzLjE0NDoyODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9uZXh0Z2VuLXNvbmV0Iiwic3ViIjoiOTE4MDcyNDktZWZlYi00ZWZlLWEwY2EtMGRlMTYxZWIzNTU5IiwidHlwIjoiU2VyaWFsaXplZC1JRCIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiJlNDZhNjFmOS01MjkxLTQ4NjItYjZmZC1lZmY3ZjJkMjIyZjIiLCJzdGF0ZV9jaGVja2VyIjoiU3VmS2tOLXE0UTNDVUhvM2xFblhHZ3NFSWdWSS0wektFR2JKRENzZHpiYyJ9.4XA6eGrUB8HhhLTfNlhY9twiX3oJLQhlFlYDY3zYa6Q; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJiABCmYTc0Ni02Y2NmLTRiMjktYTBmZC1kOWMxMWNmY2RlM2UifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NDA4ODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY0MDgwMjYyNiwianRpIjoiZWFjZDczNDctNDYyNC00Mjk0LWE4NjYtYzRiYmM1MjNiMDlhIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly8xNzIuMjYuMjMzLjE0NDoyODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9uZXh0Z2VuLXNvbmV0Iiwic3ViIjoiOTE4MDcyNDktZWZlYi00ZWZlLWEwY2EtMGRlMTYxZWIzNTU5IiwidHlwIjoiU2VyaWFsaXplZC1JRCIsInNlc3Npb25fc3phdGUiOiJlNDZhNjFmOS01MjkxAAA4NjItYjZmZC1lZmY3ZjJkMjIyZjIiLCJzdGF0ZV9jaGVja2VyIjoiU3VmS2tOLXE0UTNDVUhvM2xFblhHZ3NFSWdWSS0wektFR2JKRENzZHpiYyJ9.4XA8bGrUB8HhhLTfNlhY9twiX3oJLQhlFlYDY3zYa6Q; KEYCLOAK_SESSION=appname/91807249-efeb-4abc-a0ca-0de161eb8741/e46a61f9-2147-4862-b6fd-eff7f2d222f2; KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=name/85211234-efeb-4efe-a0ca-0de161eb1877/e46a78f9-5291-4862-b6fd-eff7f2d899f2
```

Response:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"User session not found"}
```

Comment: See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.2 how to use challenge, verifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `code_verifier` parameter needs to be **generated**, not correlated.

See the algorithm description in the [RFC 7636](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#page-8)

```
4.  Protocol

4.1.  Client Creates a Code Verifier

   The client first creates a code verifier, "code_verifier", for each
   OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] Authorization Request, in the following manner:

   code_verifier = high-entropy cryptographic random STRING using the
   unreserved characters [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
   from Section 2.3 of [RFC3986], with a minimum length of 43 characters
   and a maximum length of 128 characters.

   ABNF for "code_verifier" is as follows.

   code-verifier = 43*128unreserved
   unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
   ALPHA = %x41-5A / %x61-7A
   DIGIT = %x30-39

   NOTE: The code verifier SHOULD have enough entropy to make it
   impractical to guess the value.  It is RECOMMENDED that the output of
   a suitable random number generator be used to create a 32-octet
   sequence.  The octet sequence is then base64url-encoded to produce a
   43-octet URL safe string to use as the code verifier.
```

Sample implementation is available in the [Create Code Verifier](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce#java-sample) section of Auth0 manual

```
// Dependency: Apache Commons Codec
// https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/
// Import the Base64 class.
// import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] code = new byte[32];
sr.nextBytes(code);
String verifier = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(code);
```

you can add the following line to store the generated value into a JMeter Variable:

```
vars.put("code_verifier", verifier);
```

and use `${code_verifier}` in your HTTP Request sampler instead of the hard-coded value. In the above snippet `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details if needed.

The code can be called from i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri for all the knowledge sharing.